# Using a WCF service client and handling its exceptions

Tags: c#, beginner, error-handling, wcf

I am new to WCF and need to work with another programmer's code. I am unsure of the way the WCF service client is used here:

```
private void barButtonDocuments_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        MyServiceClient myServiceClient = new MyServiceClient();

        try
        {
            documents = myServiceClient.GetDocuments();
            // More code that isn't useful including here ...
        }
        finally
        {
            try
            {
                myServiceClient.Close();
            }
            catch
            {
            }
        }
    }
    catch (FaultException<ServiceErrorDetails> error)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(error.Detail.Message, "Erreur", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
```

Is it good practice to close the proxy in a `finally` block, and doing so in an additional `try`/`catch` block? I personally don't like the empty `catch` block because it's like hiding potentially useful exceptions when trying to close the service client.

Are there any better way of handling a WCF service client?

Comment: You may be interested in this WCF approach I asked about here: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/41692/1714

Comment: Any final _solution_ with **full source code** sample application ? _IMHO, better samples for minimize learning curve are real 

applications with full source code and good patterns_

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Although paritosh's answer is very helpful, there is additional useful information to take into account when using a service client, as found in [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733912.aspx) :

> It is recommended that a calling application open the channel, use it,
>   and close the channel inside **one** try block.

Let's look at the original try/catch block that was used for the solely purpose of closing the channel :

```
    try
    {
        myServiceClient.Close();
    }
    catch
    {
    }
```

This is useless, as stated in the article :

> Datagram channels never fault **even if exceptions occur when they are
>   closed**.

About handling exceptions, MSDN suggests that no *unexpected exceptions* (like OutOfMemoryException, ArgumentNullException or InvalidOperationException) should be caught when using a service client, as stated in [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa354510.aspx) :

> Exceptions that are thrown from communication methods on a Windows
>   Communication Foundation (WCF) client are either expected or
>   unexpected. Unexpected exceptions include catastrophic failures like
>   OutOfMemoryException and programming errors like ArgumentNullException
>   or InvalidOperationException. Typically there is no useful way to
>   handle unexpected errors, so typically you should not catch them when
>   calling a WCF client communication method.

Recommended exceptions to catch while using a service client are **TimeoutException** and any other exception that derives from **CommunicationException**.

As the article states :

> One way to handle such errors is to **abort the client** and **report
>   the communication failure.**

In addition, as this particular project handles it's own **FaultException** (of type ServiceErrorDetails), the recommended method to catch exceptions while using this service client would be to first catch any **TimeoutException**, then any **FaultException** and finally any **CommunicationException**.

The rewritten code would then look like this :

```
MyServiceClient myServiceClient = new MyServiceClient();

try
{
    documents = myServiceClient.GetDocuments();
    // More code that isn't useful including here ...
    myServiceClient.Close();
}
catch (TimeoutException exception)
{
    MessageBox.Show(exception.Message, "Timeout error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    myServiceClient.Abort();
}
catch (FaultException<ServiceErrorDetails> error)
{
    MessageBox.Show(error.Detail.Message, "Service error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    myServiceClient.Abort();
}
catch (CommunicationException exception)
{
    MessageBox.Show(exception.Message, "Communication error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    myServiceClient.Abort();
}
```

Comment: Which ***`exceptions`*** with _statusCode_ for ***do Retry*** ?

Comment: `ServiceErrorDetails` is custom class ?

Answer (score 4):

Use `Close` always for a clean path of code execution. Use `Abort` in case of a faulted channel, or if your code threw an error. As you might know, if you call `Close` on a faulted channel, it will throw another error, `Close` is a graceful shutdown of channel, whereas `Abort` is an instant shut down of the channel. Here's an example of such code:

```
MyServiceClient myServiceClient = new MyServiceClient();

try
{
    documents = myServiceClient.GetDocuments();
    // More code that isn't useful including here ...
    myServiceClient.Close();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    myServiceClient.Abort();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I didn't know about Abort(), very useful in case something's wrong with the service code. Now, I can be sure that the channel is shut down.